# iPhone Python Callback on Press

Tags: uitableview, pyobjc

So, I'm developping an app using iphone-python (aka PyObjC and UIkit)
This is my code: http://pastie.org/1718692

This displays a list, and I want to call a function, with params when one of the rows is pressed. How?

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You do it the same way you'd do it in Objective-C: make a `UITableViewDelegate` and implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` You don't register a callback; you just do whatever you need to do inside that method.